# change html string width

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have html, for ex:

```
<div id='foo' style='background:transparent;color:white;width:120px'><p>test_text_test_text_test_text_test_text_test_text_test_text_test_text</p></div>
```

how can I set to it string '\n' to it if string width more then 120? For ex. may be some like this:

```
<div id='foo' style='background:transparent;color:white;width:120px'><p>test_text_test_text\n_test_text_test_text\n_test_text_test_text\n_test_text</p></div>
```

I will be very grateful for the help

Comment: Do you want the result to be shown in the webpage, in the source code or in a text editor?

Comment: Why would you use the characters \n in text? If you actually mean **line wrapping**, then it’s a question that has been asked many times, so please search for them.

Comment: this is not clear, do you want that done serverside or clientside? some context would help, whay are you trying to do that?

Comment: Note that your text will wrap automatically at any whitespace character. Don't fool yourself by using an uncommon `test_text` without any spaces. Happened to me once ;-)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela that's why I posted my comment: if he just needs to make the source code wrap, then it's ok to put \n. Otherwise, if he wants to send text to newline in the rendered page, that's not good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use css property - word wrap

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

Example: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-wrap

Comment: Note that this is a CSS3 property only